# In order to repair these do I need to use primer and paint?

Tags: repair, drywall, repainting, crack

I am in the middle of repairing these cracks. As you can see I have worked on the two on the sides, but I am not really happy with the result I am getting so far. I used 3M fiber enhanced compound as it seemed to be the most rookie-friendly product I could find. But it is kind of hard to sand down. And I am not sure it is the best thing for crack repairs, so I haven't applied it on the middle crack, which also happens to be the largest one. I just stuck a length of mesh tape on there.

I'd like to avoid repainting the wall if possible. So my questions are: should I change to a better compound for the middle crack? Anything I should pay attention to? Do I need to use primer and paint after compound or is there a way I can avoid repainting while still get a fairly uniform and consistent result?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> should I change to a better compound for the middle crack?

It isn't about a "better compound", it's about the right product that works well for *you*. Your product is closer to spackle (a hole patching product) than drywall joint/topping compound. Although stronger, it is not surprising that it is more difficult to sand. Your product *will work*, but you may spend more energy and time getting it smooth and flat. If you hate it, try using regular joint compound. Joint compound is not as strong, takes longer to dry, and shrinks when it dries (requiring repeat applications).; **however** it is very easy to sand, and goes on creamy and smooth from your knife.

> Do I need to use primer and paint after compound

**Yes**, unless you will accept obvious patch marks on your wall and understand that the repair will be easily damaged if touched.

You need to apply several layers, each successively wider than the previous, and sand flat between each layer, if you want the patch to look good. Even then, it takes experience to create a totally unnoticable repair.

Comment: This might be a dumb question, but could wall texture work?

Comment: Well, wall texture is... textured. The stuff in a can has globs of some sort of aggregate to help match a textured surface, the stuff in a spray can is thin and weak. I think it will be difficult to make it look right with texture patch.